# Change text on duplicate notice when the question marked as a duplicate is older

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

[One question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213121/use-class-or-typename-for-template-parameters) was asked in 2008. [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/c-difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates) was asked in 2010. The question which was asked in 2008 is closed as duplicate of the question asked in 2010, with the following text:

> This question has been asked **before** and already has an answer.

Since this is impossible unless you have a time machine, the reason in situations like this should be changed to something like "this question was asked in a better format" or "this question has better answers". Otherwise, it makes no sense.

---

Edit: My question got flagged as duplicate while the other question got 6 upvotes and mine got 40 (inconsistency is unbelievable). BTW, the text says

> This question may already have an answer here

but the question doesn't have one. So, why is my question flagged instead of the other one?

Can you try to solve these subjectivity problems instead of flagging everything? The other question has already been forgotten and we all know no one would ever see it again.

---

Edit: Months have been passed and nothing has changed. Will anyone care about the site?

Comment: *Since this is impossible unless you have a time machine* -> that still doesn't make it possible. If you go back in time to ask the question, the question is still before the one that was posted in 2010.

Comment: While focused on duplicates and timeliness it could be useful to have some way to indicate that a prior answer has changed. This typically happens when new API's are released or prior API's are deprecated. As S/O ages this will become increasingly common.

Comment: @MichaelOlenick: I understand the point, but is that related to this question, or just an entirely separate issue? For example, if I close an iOS 4 question as a dup of an iOS 5 question (because it turns out nothing relevant changed between 4 and 5), and now iOS 9 makes the iOS 5 question and its accepted answer outdated, doesn't it also make the iOS 4 question just as outdated, so there's no reason to change the dup-ness?

Comment: @abamert But let's look at PHP's `mysql_*` functions -- there was a time that they were the common, accepted answer to "How do I MySQL from PHP?". Now, you're told to use other tech -- the question is still relevant, but the answer changed. In that case, you'd want to indicate that "a better answer exists [here]", which is what the question is getting at.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: But that's really the same case. If the 2010 question needs to be updated to point at the better tech, surely you don't want the 2008 question _not_ to get the same update?

Comment: @abamert And if the details of the question are _just_ different enough that someone has to write a different answer, rather than trivially copy/pasting? For example, (assuming PHP works this way; I don't know enough about it to be sure) say the 2008 question wants to do an INSERT statement. The 2010 one is all about DROPping tables. They both require an update to the new tech, but the person who just wrote out a _super good_ new answer for the latest one doesn't have the energy to write another all about INSERT. Sure, the older one should be updated, but what about in the mean time?

Comment: On a side note I've always thought it was weird that you could mark an older question as a duplicate of a newer one at all. IMO the oldest OP should get the attribution for the question